# UISegmentedControl without gaps between buttons

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiimage, uisegmentedcontrol, gaps-in-visuals

I want to remove splits (gaps) between buttons in **UISegmentedControl**. Segmented control is created with three images, each 60 pixels width, control is 180 pixels width. Style of segmented control is **UISegmentedControlStyleBar**.

But it still looks like this:
[image]

I have tried to set control width to 170 pixels or even less with no effect.

Thank you for your help.
Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to create your own customized view.

Comment: do you mean view with three buttons?

Comment: Yes you need to create a view using three buttons

Answer (score 0):

You could also call `setDividerImage:` on the segment control with an image which is the same color as your buttons.